# RDP from Vista Home Premium crashing after about 1 minute

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vpn, crash

I connect to my office through VPN. After connecting, I used to be able to remote access my office PC. Now when I connect I lose my connection after about a minute. The error that is displayed is: "mstsc.exe crashed."

Comment: Yikes, that doesn't sound good. Sounds like something rather messed on your remote box. Can you use your 30s batches of connectivity to get VNC Server rigged up? Once you've got a stable connection, I'd run Windows Update, scandisk, etc..

Comment: When was the last time that the computers were both rebooted?

Also, can you pull anything from the event viewer to see the nature of the crash?